# CMAKE passing variable into included cmake sub-file

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-modules

I'm currently configuring build of my project and decided to split `CMakeLists.txt` into subfiles which are responsible for a single build sub-task (like testing, packaging, compiling, etc...). The problem is the `cmake` subfiles needs info about how to do their tasks. So I decided to require some variables to be set before including the module. It looks like

`CpackMylib.cmake`:

```
if(NOT DEFINED MYLIB_PACKAGE_NAME)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "MYLIB_PACKAGE_NAME variable must be set")
endif()

if(NOT DEFINED MYLIB_VERSION_MAJOR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "MYLIB_VERSION_MAJOR variable must be set")
endif()

if(NOT DEFINED MYLIB_VERSION_MINOR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "MYLIB_VERSION_MINOR variable must be set")
endif()

if(NOT DEFINED MYLIB_VERSION_PATCH)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "MYLIB_VERSION_PATCH variable must be set")
endif()

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR ${MYLIB_VERSION_MAJOR})

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR ${MYLIB_VERSION_MINOR})

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH ${MYLIB_VERSION_PATCH})

set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME "${MYLIB_PACKAGE_NAME}-${MYLIB_VERSION_MAJOR}")

set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME ${MYLIB_PACKAGE_NAME}-${MYLIB_VERSION_MAJOR})

#other settings...

include(CPack)
```

And the root `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(MYLIB_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(MYLIB_VERSION_MINOR 0)
set(MYLIB_VERSION_PATCH 1)
set(MYLIB_PACKAGE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
include(cmake/CpackMylib.cmake)
```

So I require to define project-specific variables that will be used for creation packages using `CPack`. I'm new to `CMake` and this just seems natural to do things that way. But I'm not sure if it is sort of common approach when dealing with `CMake`.

Does it make sense to define all variable the `CMake` submodules needs and provide them in the root `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Why do you `set` the version numbers instead of providing it in your [`project`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) command? And if you don't have a `project` command, then I suggest you add one.

Comment: "Does it make sense to define all variable the `CMake` submodules needs and provide them in the root `CMakeLists.txt`?" - I don't understand the problem. If submodules **needs** that variables, then you **need** to set them. But as the previous commenter notes, in CMake there are many variables with predefined semantic and which sometimes are set automatically. So, if a submodule needs some information from the top-level project, firstly check whether this information is provided by some well-known variable with a predefined semantic.